# How to get the name of a UIColor?

Tags: nsstring, uicolor

I have an array of UIColors like

```
[UIColor blueColor];
```

is it possible to get the name "blue" from that UIColor, to display it in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in to UIKit, but Erica Sadun's [uicolor-utilities library](https://github.com/erica/uicolor-utilities) adds similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can get RGB and Alpha of the UIColor, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A list of color names can be obtained using `runtime`.
See my question: [How to get all Color methods of UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846964/how-to-get-all-color-methods-of-uicolor#34847052)

You can also use string methods to convert `'xxxColor'` to `'xxx'` if needed.