# How to find current background colour of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uicolor

How do I find the current background color of `UIButton` and store that color name in `NSString` or NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### uicolors don't have all have names

**BUT** you can use erica sudan's category

[How to get the name of a UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582801/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-uicolor)

it finds the closest color name given a color

(disclaimer: not my code there)

### alternatively use hex values:

see https://github.com/timd/UIColor-HexValues

it has a category on UIColor to go from color to hex as well from hex to color

(disclaimer: not my code there)

Comment: that helped me! but it gives "FF7F00" when I press orange button.

Comment: how to parse the hex to string ?

Comment: i dont want the hex value I just need color name ? plz help

Comment: uicolors don't have all have names

Answer (score 0):

Here you go my friend.

```
UIColor* buttonColor = button.backgroundColor;
NSString* colorString = [buttonColor description];
```

Comment: this won't get you the colorstring

Comment: how to get the color name ?